# Doctrine DQL query rewrite to Query Builder

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have query

```
$Select = 'SELECT COUNT(o.Id) FROM Entities\Order o';
```

How to rewrite this query for query builder?

```
$qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select(.....
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very straight forward as you can see in the [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/query-builder.html#helper-methods).

```
$qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$result = $qb->select('COUNT(o.Id)')
    ->from('Entities\Order', 'o')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

If you just want to have the number in `$result` you can use

```
$qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$result = $qb->select('COUNT(o.Id)')
    ->from('Entities\Order', 'o')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getSingleScalarResult();
```